# Suspense/Await - infinite loop after resolved data is loaded/saved to state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When the `loaderData` is resolved in the `Await` component I want to pass it as props to `PostList` component (which is working) and also save it in `displayState`, which is working however it's creating an infinite loop.

```
const {loaderData}= useLoaderData()
const[displayState, dispatchDisplayState]=useReducer(..........

.....

return(
    <Suspense fallback={<p style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontWeight:'bold' }}>Loading...</p>}>
        <Await resolve={loaderData}>
            {
                (loaderData)=>(
                <>
                    <PostList {...loaderData}  />
                {
                   dispatchDataState({type:"LOAD_DATA", data:{loaderData} });
                }
                </>
                )
            }
        </Await>
    </Suspense>
);
```

[image: CONSOLE output]

Anyone knows how to get this working without the infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is unconditionally enqueueing a state update as an unintentional side-effect. This creates the render loop.

I suggest abstracting the state update into a React component that enqueues the state update as an ***intentional*** side-effect.

Example:

```
const SaveDisplayState = ({ loaderData, dispatchDisplayState }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatchDataState({
      type: "LOAD_DATA",
      data: { loaderData }
    });
  }, [loaderData, dispatchDisplayState]);

  return null;
};
```

```
const { loaderData } = useLoaderData()
const[displayState, dispatchDisplayState] = useReducer(...);

...

return (
  <Suspense
    fallback={(
      <p style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
        Loading...
      </p>
    )}
  >
    <Await resolve={loaderData}>
      {(loaderData) => (
        <>
          <PostList {...loaderData}  />
          <SaveDisplayState {...{ loaderData, dispatchDisplayState }} />
        </>
      )}
    </Await>
  </Suspense>
);
```

Comment: This is working. However I'm now learning react, could you expand more on your quote: "that enqueues the state update as an intentional side-effect". Is it because that the update is in a component outside the main component, when it updates it won't trigger the re-render of the return statement which was causing the infinite loop?

Comment: @D.Rattansingh Sure. The previous code was just updating state which triggers a rerender, which updates state and triggers another rerender... all outside the React component lifecycle. By using the `useEffect` hook with the appropriate dependency, e.g. `loaderData`, the effect is only run when a dependency changes. So long as `loaderData` reference doesn't change (*`dispatchDisplayState` is already a stable reference*) the component will only render once and issue the intended side-effect once.